# Why is my ASPX page so slow to load after a compile?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a .Net solution with 2 websites in it (one customer facing, one admin). They both share a Code Library that acts as a data/business layer.

When I make changes to my site(s) and recompile the code library, then browse to a page, it takes ages to load; like several minutes.

I understand it might take a bit longer to load up changed code into memory, but this is far too long.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can work out what's going wrong?

I'm thinking there might be some dodgey settings in my project files? Or maybe something dumb in IIS (which happens to be IIS6).

I'm keen for any reading on this topic if anyone would like to point me to some!

Thanks in advance.

-Ev

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: just check the system RAM or other resources which may cause it. Try to recompile the solution

Comment: @Ev maybe this answer solve your problems ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382741/slow-performance-asp-net-aspnet-wp-exe-and-csc-exe-running-after-clicking-red/2385097#2385097

Answer (score 2):

May be it's because of how you're deploying the site.

Try this: in Visual Studio, go to Build Site and then Publish Site in a directory on your local hard drive. On the server (not on the production server for your first try!), remove every file you have. Backup the database(s) to .bak files and reattach the backup files to the SQL server. FTP the files from your local hard drive to the site.

This way of doing the deployment ensures that you're only working with fully compiled aspx files and that all your AppCode is in .dll format.

If this doesn't change the speed at which the site loads, then you know it's an IIS problem.

Comment: Thanks @frenchie. That's an excellent idea. Do you still recommend this approach considerign my solution is made up of websites (in oppose to web appliations), plus one code library DLL?

Comment: Best is try it out and see what happens. Some of the pages in my web app are also purely static HTML but I always rebuild the entire solution with every single file, including the static ones (html, js and css) before FTPing. I also wipe out everything clean with only the static "we're down for maintenance" page in the root. Let me know if your site startup time improves.