# What are the startup process steps for an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, performance, startup

My main goal: make development faster by not having to wait as long each time I change the code of my site.

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application in Visual Studio 2010.  While developing, I normally run the app with "Control+F5" (ie. start w/o debugging).  This starts up the built-in ASP.NET Development Server.  However, when I modify code and do this, I get the following:

-Press Control+F5
-The modified project(s) in my solution build
-The web-server is started (if it's not already)
-My browser opens & waits

At this point there's a 15-30 second delay before I see the first page.  Reloading a page is instant, as well as modifying an .aspx page and reloading.  But changing any code & recompiling causes another 15-30 second delay.

First, I'm trying to see where that time is spent (which is the point of this question).  Looking at the log file, there's about 5 seconds until my global.asax.cs file runs.  Then a wait of 10-15 seconds, then my Site.master.cs file runs.  What is running in that time in between?  What files does ASP.NET run and in what order?

Second, I can see that some of this time is spent with "csc.exe", which leads me to believe that the pages are being compiled-on-request.  Can I precompile this code (again, using the built-in web server, not IIS) and will this be faster?

I'm open to other suggestions on how to make this faster.  I want to minimize the time between modifying code & seeing changes on the site.  There are multiple projects in this solution.  One project uses the other as a reference.  I'm on XP.  I can use XP's IIS if that will make things faster.  Any ideas?

Thnaks!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382741/slow-performance-asp-net-aspnet-wp-exe-and-csc-exe-running-after-clicking-re/2385097#2385097

Comment: Get more memory or perhaps another PC. XP.... really?

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious about the internal processes and architecture of asp.net and IIS work then follow this link.. may be you will get your problem point on which you want to work.

[low-level Look at the ASP.NET Architecture](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)

and have look on this question somewhat similar to yours as  Aristos comment on your question.

[Slow Performance -- ASP .NET ASPNET_WP.EXE and CSC.EXE Running After Clicking Redirect Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382741/slow-performance-asp-net-aspnet-wp-exe-and-csc-exe-running-after-clicking-re/2385097#2385097)