# ASP.NET jQuery - how to invoke server method when asynchronous method is complete?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have jQuery plugin - progress bar. How to invoke server side method on success? The code is below:

(Everything works fine)

```
 $("#<%=this.btnGetData.ClientID%>").click(
            function () {
                intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 100); 

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ProgressBar.aspx/ExecuteImport",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (msg)
                    {
                        //HERE should be invoke
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }
        );
```

Comment: It is in the WebForms project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we've established this in WebForms then you can use an ASP.NET AJAX callback to a web method placed in your aspx file.

First, create your server side method in C# (or .NET language of choice) and annotate it with the [ScriptMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx) and [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(VS.80).aspx) attributes, like so:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
public static void MyServerMethod(string myArgument)
{
        // Do something
}
```

Then in your aspx file you need to add a ScriptManager with PageMethods enabled:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Then call it from your jQuery success event:

```
success: function (msg)
{
     PageMethods.MyServerMethod(msg);
}
```

I'm basing this on [my Hidden Features of ASP.NET answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net/1161881#1161881) (which is not jQuery specific). However, for more details about using jQuery with WebMethods have a read of [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Answer (score 0):

For the VB fans out there, here is my implementation of Dan's answer above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function EmailManagers_Click() {
        PageMethods.EmailManagers("hello");
        return false;
    }
</script>



  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub EmailManagers(myArgument As String)
        Dim x = myArgument
    End Sub
```