# How do I send email to files in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, email, web-config

I remember reading somewhere that it's possible to configure your web.config to send email to files, instead of setting up a real SMTP server for development. How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hidden Features of ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net/75170#75170)

Comment: Nice. That's exactly where I got it from in the first place.

Comment: One can use emlOpenView (http://bitdaddys.com/emlopenview.html) to view the resulting .eml files.