# Jquery load usercontrol using generic handler

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to load usercontrol using jquery. I created a handler class and loaded usercontrol through that. The jquery part is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HandlerAdminManageDataSideMenu.ashx",
    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success" + data);
        $(".admin_side_menu").append(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
        alert("Error Occured!");
    }
});
```

My handler file looks like :

```vb
Public Class HandlerAdminManageDataSideMenu
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        'context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        'context.Response.Write("Hello World!")

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        context.Response.Write(RenderPartialToString("Shared\AdminManageDataSideMenu.ascx"))
    End Sub

    Private Function RenderPartialToString(ByVal controlName As String) As String
        Dim page As New Page()
        Dim control As Control = page.LoadControl(controlName)
        page.Controls.Add(control)

        Dim writer As New StringWriter()
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, False)

        Return writer.ToString()
    End Function

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The line `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, False)` throws error:

> Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/491233/335105 see if this solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made slight changes to RenderPartialToString function:

```
    Private Function RenderPartialToString(ByVal controlName As String) As String

    Dim page As New Page()
    Dim usercontrol As UserControl = CType(page.LoadControl(controlName), UserControl)

    usercontrol.EnableViewState = False
    Dim form As HtmlForm = New HtmlForm()
    form.Controls.Add(usercontrol)
    page.Controls.Add(form)

    Dim textWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, False)
    Return textWriter.ToString()

End Function
```

Reference link : http://www.aspxtutorial.com/post/2011/01/02/Load-aspnet-web-user-control-using-jQuery-and-web-method.aspx

Thanks for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can use .load() instead. http://api.jquery.com/load/

"Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element."

Sample from the link I gave to you:

```
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

Comment: I need to load a usercontrol not a webpage as such