# ASP.NET stop application load from Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, global-asax

Is there any way to prevent an ASP.NET application from loading within the Application_Start event?

```
Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/")
        Dim src As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path & "src.js")
        Dim check As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path & "check.js")

        If Not String.Equals(src, check, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
            'Stop application from loading here
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: How about redirecting visitor to an offline_page?

Comment: Missing some context here...if the app isn't supposed to do anything, then shut it down or [`app_offline.htm`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55310/304683).

Comment: I think the above comment is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some pre-checks and prevent the application from starting if the check fails, you can throw an exception in a static constructor of the `HttpApplication`:

```
Sub New()
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/")
    Dim src As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path & "src.js")
    Dim check As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path & "check.js")

    If Not String.Equals(src, check, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
        Throw New System.Exception("Cannot start-up application, because...")
    End If
End Sub
```

This will prevent the application from being instantiated, and every following request will fail. If the check succeeds, it will not re-check on every request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub  Application_AuthenticateRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
    If Not String.Equals(src, check, StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
         HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    End If
```

Comment: Looks like that fires on every page request, I guess I would have to store those two strings in two HttpRuntime.Cache variables maybe in order to access them without hitting the file system every page load?

Comment: @Dude2TheN Yes, you're right, but that is not the scope of the answer. I really don't know what are you trying to achieve. Maybe some kind of custom authentication? `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` is what you are asking for. `Application_Start` will run only once when the web app is loaded in IIS, that is why I used `Application_AuthenticateRequest`.