# Can app_offline.hml be localized?

Tags: asp.net, iis, localization, maintenance-mode

We can use [app_offline.html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310/921054) as a landing page for the period of a maintenance work. But is it possible to localize this page?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and can think of, it is not possible to have localized versions of the app_offline page.

Asp.net is only looking for that page to bring the site down and since it is a static page there is not much options.

Simplest approach would be to display a page with the content in all languages. This is not very elegant but would be simple and efficient especially if the content is short and you only have few languages.

If you have too many languages and/or content is too large, you could also have several div each with the translated content and display the correct div by doing language detection in JavaScript.

If you want/need to have a more sophisticated solution, you could look at JavaScript Localization frameworks ([l10n.js](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/) or [l20n.js](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js)) to achieve the same thing.

If you go that route, remember that you will need another website to host all the necessary JS and resource files.